# Refencing data.table colulmn names from within brackets

Tags: regex, r, data.table

I'd like to create a function "startswith' to be used within brackets in data.table. It should return a character vector containing the column names that begin with the character provided. For example

```
DT <- data.table(x=1, y=2, z1=1, z2=2)
# the syntax DT[, startswith("z")] is equivalent to  
DT[, .(z1, z2)]
# returns
   z1 z2
1:  1  2
```

I'm familiar with grep to search for text expressions, but am having trouble finding a way to refer to the column names of DT from within the brackets. One solution I attempted was to use ls() and the environment associated with DT to list all of the columns in DT, but I haven't found a way to refer to this environment from within the brackets.

The goal is to create a wrapper for grep to be used as a convenience function. I don't want to have to specify the DT from within the brackets.

Comment: Maybe the data.table developers can add a `.COLNAMES` object (like `.I`,`.BY`, et al), to be used inside the brackets for things like this. Personally, I would just do this sort of operation in two lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surely there is a more idiomatic approach, but this is what I came up with:

```
startswith <- function(pattern = "z") {

  re <- paste0("^", pattern)

  call_info <- deparse(sys.calls()[[1]])

  if (grepl("(^.+\\()(.+)(\\)$)",call_info)) {
    this_name <- sub("(^.+\\()(.+)(\\)$)","\\2",call_info)
  } else {
    this_name <- strsplit(call_info,"\\[")[[1]][1]
  }

  this <- copy(get(this_name))
  this_names <- names(this)

  eval.parent(grep(re,this_names))

}
```

---

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(x=1, y=2, z1=1, z2=2)
##
R> DT[,.(z1, z2)]
   z1 z2
1:  1  2
##
R> DT[,startswith(), with=F]
   z1 z2
1:  1  2
```

---

I had to add in that `if () {} else {}` block so that this could be used inside of functions, e.g.

```
Foo <- function(gt) {
  f <- gt[,startswith(),with=F]
  # {do something interesting with f}
  f
}
##
R> Foo(DT)
   z1 z2
1:  1  2
```

---

I think this is an interesting question though - to my knowledge, R doesn't have a concept of something like [the `this` pointer in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this), but it would certainly be useful in situations like this. Essentially, all of my hackery with `sys.call`, `get`, etc... was just so I could retrieve the names of the calling object.

Comment: Nice function. You came up with it on your own?

Comment: Why do you use `copy(get(this_name))` and not just `get(this_name)`?

Comment: @AnandaMahto I guess it's just a habit I've fallen into with `data.table`s because sometimes I'm not completely sure about whether or not the changes I make to the local object when modifying by reference will propagate to the original `data.table`. Although I'm not doing any modify-by-reference in this case, so you're right in that the use of `copy` is unnecessary here.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thank you, yes I did. To be honest though I was hoping that someone would have a cleaner solution because I think there are still some issues with this approach. For example, if the enclosing function `Foo` from my example had multiple arguments, I'm not sure that `startswith` would work properly.

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of `data.table` support pattern searching in `.SDcols`:

```
DT <- data.table(x=1, y=2, z1=1, z2=2)
DT[, .SD, .SDcols = patterns('^z')]
#    z1 z2
# 1:  1  2
```

Comment: The point is to create a wrapper for grep to be used as a convenience function. I don't want to have to specify the DT from within the brackets.