# Select columns of data.table based on regex

Tags: regex, r, data.table

How can I select columns of a data.table based on a regex?
Consider a simple example as follows:

```r
library(data.table)
mydt <- data.table(foo=c(1,2), bar=c(2,3), baz=c(3,4))
```

Is there a way to use columns of `bar` and `baz` from the datatable based on a regex? I know that the following solution works but if the table is much bigger and I would like to choose more variables this could easily get cumbersome.

```r
mydt[, .(bar, baz)]
```

I would like to have something like `matches()` in `dplyr::select()` but only by reference.

Comment: You could do `mydt[, grep(c("bar|baz"), names(mydt)), with = FALSE]` but I think `with` creates a copy.

Comment: Might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13383840 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/12603890

Comment: @DavidArenburg Don't think it creates a copy.

Comment: @nicola I remember Arun mentioning it several times but never checked really

Comment: @DavidArenburg good to know. Cannot think a reason why it happens, but if Arun said that it's obvious true. I'm gonna make some research to understand the reason.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, that would be pretty strange behavior, no?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I updated the comparison with @sindri_baldur's answer - using version  `1.12.6`. According to the results, `patterns()` is a handy shortcut, but if performance matters, one should stick with the `..` or `with = FALSE` solution (see below).

---

Apparently, there is a new way of achieving this from version 1.10.2 onwards.

```r
library(data.table)
cols <- grep("bar|baz", names(mydt), value = TRUE)
mydt[, ..cols]
```

It seems to work the fastest out of the posted solutions.

```r
# Creating a large data.table with 100k rows, 32 columns
n <- 100000
foo_cols <- paste0("foo", 1:30)
big_dt <- data.table(bar = rnorm(n), baz = rnorm(n))
big_dt[, (foo_cols) := rnorm(n)]

# Methods
subsetting <- function(dt) {
    subset(dt, select = grep("bar|baz", names(dt)))
}

usingSD <- function(dt) {
    dt[, .SD, .SDcols = names(dt) %like% "bar|baz"]
}

usingWith <- function(dt) {
    cols <- grep("bar|baz", names(dt), value = TRUE)
    dt[, cols, with = FALSE]
}

usingDotDot <- function(dt) {
    cols <- grep("bar|baz", names(dt), value = TRUE)
    dt[, ..cols]
}

usingPatterns <- function(dt) {
  dt[, .SD, .SDcols = patterns("bar|baz")]
}

# Benchmark
microbenchmark(
    subsetting(big_dt), usingSD(big_dt), usingWith(big_dt), usingDotDot(big_dt), usingPatterns(big_dt),
    times = 5000
)

#Unit: microseconds
#                  expr  min   lq  mean median    uq    max neval
#    subsetting(big_dt)  430  759  1672   1309  1563  82934  5000
#       usingSD(big_dt)  547  951  1872   1461  1797  60357  5000
#     usingWith(big_dt)  278  496  1331   1112  1304  62656  5000
#   usingDotDot(big_dt)  289  483  1392   1117  1344  55878  5000
# usingPatterns(big_dt)  596 1019  1984   1518  1913 120331  5000
```

Comment: From the data.table [news](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/news.html): "When j is a symbol prefixed with `..` it will be looked up in calling scope and its value taken to be column names or numbers. (...) think one-level-up like the directory `..` in all operating systems meaning the parent directory (...) It is experimental."

Comment: Fwiw, I think if speed matters for this, then the code must have some organizational problem. A bad but faster way on my system: `microbenchmark(bad = \`[.noquote\`(big_dt, names(big_dt) %like% "bar|baz"), good = big_dt[, .SD, .SDcols = names(big_dt) %like% "bar|baz"])` Similar `setDT(as.list(big_dt)[names(big_dt) %like% "bar|baz"])`

Comment: you forgot the last one, usingPatterns, in the microbenchmark test :)

Comment: thanks @emilBeBri, it was only included in the results. I updated the code.

Answer (score 36):

You can also try to use `%like%` from `data.table` package, which is a "convenience function for calling regexpr". However makes code more readable ;)

In this case, answering your question:

```
mydt[, .SD, .SDcols = names(mydt) %like% "bar|baz"]
```

As `%like%` returns a logical vector, whe can use the following to get every column except those which contain "foo":

```
mydt[, .SD, .SDcols = ! names(mydt) %like% "foo"]
```

where `!`negates the logical vector.

Answer (score 17):

David's answer will work. But if your regex is long and you would rather it be done first, try:

```
cols <- grep("<regex pattern>", names(mydt), value=T)
mydt[, cols, with=FALSE]
```

It just depends on your preferences and needs. You can also assign the subsetted table to a chosen variable if you need the original intact.

Answer (score 17):

Since `data.table v1.12.0` (Jan 2019) you can do:

```
mydt[, .SD, .SDcols = patterns("bar|baz")]
```

From the official documentation `?data.table`, on the `.SDcols` argument:

> [...] you can filter columns to include in `.SD` based on their *names* according to regular
> expressions via `.SDcols=patterns(regex1, regex2, ...)`. The included
> columns will be the *intersection* of the columns identified by each
> pattern; pattern unions can easily be specified with `|` in a regex. [...] You
> can also invert a pattern as usual with `.SDcols = !patterns(...)`.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed a long-awaited feature of data.table. I updated my benchmark with it. It seems to work slower but in many cases, it does not matter at all.

Answer (score 6):

There is also a `subset` method for "data.table", so you can always use something like the following:

```
subset(mydt, select = grep("bar|baz", names(mydt)))
#    bar baz
# 1:   2   3
# 2:   3   4
```

It [turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29437290/1270695) that creating a `startswith` type of function for "data.table" is not very straightforward.

Comment: Hmm I wonder why OP prefers this over `mydt[, grep(c("bar|baz"), names(mydt)), with = FALSE]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg, it's marginally faster?

Comment: Have you tested it? Would be interesting find. I never used `subset` in my life, but if this is faster, I may give it a chance.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, `tracemem` doesn't show any copies with `with`.

Comment: So why would it be slower than `subset` than?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, as the search becomes more complex, the standard approach seems to be faster.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest this one-liner code for readability and performance.

```
mydt[,names(mydt) %like% "bar|baz", with=F]
```

Following @Janosdivenji's answer: 
See `usingLike`on the last row

```
Unit: microseconds
                  expr     min        lq     mean    median        uq       max neval
    subsetting(big_dt) 370.582  977.2760 1194.875 1016.4340 1096.9285  25750.94  5000
       usingSD(big_dt) 554.330 1084.8530 1352.039 1133.4575 1226.9060 189905.39  5000
     usingWith(big_dt) 238.481  832.7505 1017.051  866.6515  927.8460  22717.83  5000
   usingDotDot(big_dt) 256.005  844.8770 1101.543  878.9935  936.6040 181855.43  5000
 usingPatterns(big_dt) 569.787 1128.0970 1411.510 1178.2895 1282.2265 177415.23  5000
     usingLike(big_dt) 262.868  852.5805 1059.466  887.3455  948.6665  23971.70  5000
```

Comment: this is the same as the `usingWith` solution - regarding the question it is irrelevant if the `cols` are chosen by using `%like%`or `grep()`