# Select data.table columns with grep-like partial matching

Tags: r, data.table, pattern-matching

At the moment, when trying to select columns not directly by their name, but rather with `grepl`, one has to add an additional call to the `data.table` in the `grepl` command using `colnames()`. Is it possible to directly implement this functionality into data.table, so that one could use `grepl` directly and the column names are automatically taken from the current data.table.

```
dt <- structure(list(Global.Company.Key = c(1380L, 1380L, 1380L, 1380L, 1380L)
                         , Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter = structure(c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000), class = "yearqtr")
                         , Current.Assets.Total = c(2218, 2218, 2218, 2218, 2218)
                         , DRILL_TYPE = c("U", "D", "V", "H", "U")
                         , DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter = c(18395.6792379842, 1301949.24041659, 235.311086392291, 27261.8049684835, 4719.27956989249)
                         , DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter = c(1600471.27107983, 4882347.22928982, 2611.60215053765, 9634.76418242493, 27648.276603634)), .Names = c("Global.Company.Key", "Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter", "Current.Assets.Total", "DRILL_TYPE", "DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter",  "DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table",  "data.frame"), sorted = c("Global.Company.Key",  "Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter"))
```

One example for a selection based with grepl:

```
dt[, grepl(glob2rx("Current.Assets*"), colnames(dt)), with = FALSE]
```

It would be nice, if something like this would be possible instead:

```
dt[, grepl(glob2rx("Current.Assets*")), with = FALSE]
```

Comment: can you specify what is `glob2rx`?

Comment: `glob2rx` is just my way to get around regex, because it allows to use * as wildcard.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, while you're asking for a new feature. The FR is already posted, btw: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1878 and https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1786

Comment: I didn't find it, sorry. Should I remove the question or keep it as a reference to the feature request?

Comment: Up to you. I think it's fine either way. If you want to keep it as a ref, you could drop a comment on one of the issues like "please update / answer this SO post if this is implemented".

Comment: Am I missing something or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40129395/1274242) would solve the issue? `dt[, .SD, .SDcols = names(dt) %like% "Current.Assets"]`

Comment: @fridaymeetssunday, my problem is pretty much the same as in https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1878#issuecomment-256406057 because in my case the `data.table` I am referring to is a pretty complicated subset, so the code becomes quite messy to say the least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(CurrentAssets=rnorm(10),FixedAssets=rnorm(10), CurrentLiabilities=rnorm(10),Capital=rnorm(10))
```

dt

```
##    CurrentAssets FixedAssets CurrentLiabilities    Capital
## 1:   -1.27610992  -0.2989316         0.20688252  0.6504636
## 2:    0.01065576   1.3088539         1.22533006  0.7550024
## 3:    0.53308022  -1.3459419        -0.99627142 -0.7589336
## 4:    0.30737237  -0.4291044         2.20328357  0.2157515
## 5:   -1.37391990   0.8581097        -0.08161687  0.7067757
## 6:    0.28664468   0.2308479         0.38675487 -0.3467660
## 7:   -0.22902454   1.3365470         0.10128697  0.3246363
## 8:    0.05159736  -2.0702850         0.78404464 -1.7612696
## 9:    0.51817847  -0.8365225        -0.04778573  0.6170114
##10:    0.50859575   0.5683021        -0.13780167 -0.9243434
```

Just some random columns. The accounts don't balance.
You can define the columns, then do ...

```
colnames <- c("CurrentAssets","FixedAssets", "CurrentLiabilities","Capital")
dt[,.SD,.SDcols=grep("Assets",colnames,value =TRUE)]
```

If you don't want to type `colnames` and `value=TRUE` all the time you can build your own function like the following.

```
mygrep <- function(x){
    colnames <- c("CurrentAssets","FixedAssets", "CurrentLiabilities","Capital")
    grep(x,colnames,value=TRUE)
}
```

Now the drawback is of `mygrep` is that you need to put the column name manually. An improvement would be to pass the data.table to the function.

```
mygrep <- function(x,dt){
    colnames <- colnames(dt)
    grep(x,colnames,value=TRUE)
}

dt[,.SD,.SDcols=mygrep("Assets",dt)]
```

**Edit**
Just found another way to do the same thing using macro in R. You will need the package gtools to use macros.

We define a macro `subdt`.

```
library(gtools)
  subdt <- defmacro(dt,pattern,expr={
   dt[,.SD,.SDcols=grep(pattern,colnames(dt),value=TRUE)]
    })
```

then do

```
subdt(dt,"Assets")
```

macros are powerful as they write the code before evaluation.

Comment: Made my code much more readable, although it's not the final solution, probably the best available.

Comment: I wonder if @DJJ could provide a brief explanation why (example on mtcars) `mtcars_dt[,.SD,.SDcols = grep("m", colnames(mtcars_dt), value =TRUE)]` needs to be used for data.table while for `data.frame` the following works `mtcars[, grepl("m", colnames(mtcars))]` (but not for `data.table`)? This could helps others understand further the differences in data.table and data.frame. I recently tackled the same issue and your answer was the solution but I still wonder how it works in data.table and why base approach had to be adapted.

Comment: @gofraidh I would suggest posting a question on SO. There are people with more knowledge than me about data.table. If you have yet read it [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html#what-is-datatable-1a) is a good starting point. For data.table, a solution would be the following. `tmp <- grepl("m", colnames(aa)); aa[,..tmp]`

Comment: Now, data.table has also the `patterns` key. `aa<- as.data.table(mtcars); aa[,.SD,.SDcols=patterns("m")]`. see `?data.table` for more details.