# Ignoring case in d(b)plyr verbs

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr

The database I am querying does not respect case when it comes to column names. for example the following columns exist in different tables:

`PERSONID
PERSONiD
PersonID
Personid
PersonId`

Using standard d(b)plyr verbs is getting very frustrating. Is it possible to turn off the case sensitivity for dbplyr verbs?

Comment: what database platform are you using?

Comment: PostgreSQL for example returns column names in all lower case, while Oracle returns them in all upper case. If you want to write code that will run on either platform, you have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can change all of the column names of your result to a consistent case with `rename_all`. For example to make them all lower case:

```
rename_all(df, tolower)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done by using regular expression when selecing data columns.

A very much similar question with answer can be found at [select-columns-of-data-table-based-on-regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30189979/select-columns-of-data-table-based-on-regex).

In your case, regular expression might be written as [Pp][Ee][Rr][Ss][Ii][Dd].

Answer (score 0):

Or you can change the column names of your dataframe (df) to lowercase using:

```
 names(df) <- tolower(names(df))
```

Comment: Or start the chain by `tbl(con, df) %>% rename_all(toupper) %>% ...`, not sure if it's supported though

Comment: Yes, it is supported. It's one of the examples in the [docs](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select_all.html).