# Get rid of pattern not found in selecting column with regex data.table

Tags: r, list, data.table

I have a list containing multiple `data.table` and all of them might have different columns. Some of the tables inside are containing unwanted columns which I want to get rid of them. Suppose they're called `"zRemoveThis1", "zRemoveThis2", "zRemoveThis3"` etc. Here's a sample of my data.

```r
library(data.table)

dt_list <- list(
  item_1 = data.table(ID = paste(1:3, "item_1", sep = "_"),
                      Count_A = c(11:13),
                      Count_B = c(14:16),
                      zRemoveThis1 = c(14:16),
                      count_C = c(17:19),
                      zRemoveThis2 = c(24:26)),
  item_2 = data.table(ID = paste(1:3, "item_2", sep = "_"),
                      Count_A = c(1:3),
                      Count_B = c(4:6),
                      count_C = c(7:9))
)
```

I already followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30189979/select-columns-of-data-table-based-on-regex), but then I encountered a new problem. When I applied the `patterns()` with `lapply` to my list, it didn't work.

```r
lapply(dt_list, function(x) { x[, .SD, .SDcols = ! patterns("zRemoveThis*")] })
#> Error in do_patterns(colsub, names_x): Pattern not found: [zRemoveThis*]
```

But when I applied the function individually, it worked on the first item of the list, but not on the second one.

```r
#WORK
dt_list$item_1[, .SD, .SDcols = ! patterns("zRemoveThis*")]
#>          ID Count_A Count_B count_C
#> 1: 1_item_1      11      14      17
#> 2: 2_item_1      12      15      18
#> 3: 3_item_1      13      16      19

#DIDN'T WORK
dt_list$item_2[, .SD, .SDcols = ! patterns("zRemoveThis*")]
#> Error in do_patterns(colsub, names_x): Pattern not found: [zRemoveThis*]
```

I found out that the problem is the function won't work if there is no matching pattern. So I have an idea to this ugly if-else solution, yet it worked.

```r
lapply(dt_list, function(x) {
  if (any(grepl("zRemoveThis", colnames(x)))) {
    return(x[, .SD, .SDcols = ! patterns("zRemoveThis*")])
  } else return(x)
})
#> $item_1
#>          ID Count_A Count_B count_C
#> 1: 1_item_1      11      14      17
#> 2: 2_item_1      12      15      18
#> 3: 3_item_1      13      16      19
#> 
#> $item_2
#>          ID Count_A Count_B count_C
#> 1: 1_item_2       1       4       7
#> 2: 2_item_2       2       5       8
#> 3: 3_item_2       3       6       9
```

My question is, is there any sophisticated `data.table` solution to my problem? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can directly subset by specifying the column name pattern in `.SDcols` and return the `.SD` (Subset of data.table) as these are `data.table` objects after looping over the `list` with `lapply`

```
library(data.table)
lapply(dt_list, function(x) x[, .SD,
       .SDcols = -startsWith(names(x), 'zRemoveThis')])
$item_1
         ID Count_A Count_B count_C
1: 1_item_1      11      14      17
2: 2_item_1      12      15      18
3: 3_item_1      13      16      19

$item_2
         ID Count_A Count_B count_C
1: 1_item_2       1       4       7
2: 2_item_2       2       5       8
3: 3_item_2       3       6       9
```

---

Or use `tidyverse`, loop over the `list` with `map`, and `select` the columns that are not (`-`) having pattern that `starts_with` 'zRemoveThis'

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(dt_list, ~ .x %>% 
          select(-starts_with('zRemoveThis')))
$item_1
         ID Count_A Count_B count_C
1: 1_item_1      11      14      17
2: 2_item_1      12      15      18
3: 3_item_1      13      16      19

$item_2
         ID Count_A Count_B count_C
1: 1_item_2       1       4       7
2: 2_item_2       2       5       8
3: 3_item_2       3       6       9
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I combined your idea with Ronak's idea and found the solution perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You may use `grepl` -

```
lapply(dt_list, function(x) {
  cols <- !grepl('zRemoveThis', names(x))
  x[, ..cols]
})

#$item_1
#         ID Count_A Count_B count_C
#1: 1_item_1      11      14      17
#2: 2_item_1      12      15      18
#3: 3_item_1      13      16      19

#$item_2
#         ID Count_A Count_B count_C
#1: 1_item_2       1       4       7
#2: 2_item_2       2       5       8
#3: 3_item_2       3       6       9
```